# Como crear un evento paste con Javascript

Tags: javascript, eventos

Quiero crear un evento en el que cuando se dispare en un input en especifico yo con JavaScript pegue sin la necesidad de tipear en el teclado y escriba en el input un valor que el evento le especifique.

Pongase el ejemplo:

Tengo un input:

```
document.getElementById("myinput");
```

quiero entonces en ese input pegar el texto: Hola!

Aclaro no es poner:

```
document.getElementById("myinput").vale = "Hola!";
```

es crear un evento con el objeto KeyboardEvent o Event(No conozco los argumentos, he buscado pero no hay mucha especificación) y que el evento entonces pegue el texto.

Comment: Que se copie lo que especifiques en un campo dado, cuando ocurra un evento, no tiene mucho que ver con crear un evento en sí. Más bien es añadir un *listener* a un evento.

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar el evento `focus` que es cuando seleccionas por así decirlo el input, de esta manera aparecerá el texto *'¡Hola!'*, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
let input = document.getElementById('mensaje');

input.addEventListener('focus', function(){

  this.value = '¡Hola!';

})
```

```html
Mensaje: <input type="text" id="mensaje">
```

Answer (score 1):

Quieres detectar cuando una persona pega contenido dentro de un input, si mal no entiendo. Lo puedes hacer de esta manera:

```js
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {

  if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 86) 
     console.log("Paste on windows or linux")

  if(e.keyCode == 91 && e.keyCode == 86)
     console.log("Paste on MacOs")

 
})
```

```html
<input/>
```

Edito: Si en realidad lo que quieres es que JS simule como si el usuario hubiera pegado algo, no se puede. Todo es por temas de seguridad, imagina que alguien haya copiado alguna información valiosa y como la tiene en el portapapeles, tu podrías enviártela de alguna manera... Si es eso lo que quieres no es posible :/

Comment: Entonces de ser así, podría simular entonces desde JavaScript un comportamiento de escritura pero desde JavaScript usando el KeyboardEvent?

Comment: No entendí bien tu pregunta, ¿a que te refieres?

Comment: Crear con JavaScript un código que simule que un usuario escribe un texto con eventos de teclado como el KeyboardEvent, haciendo un dispatchEvent en el input donde quiero que se genere el texto con JavaScript.